# Polar exponential form of -i

Tags: complex-numbers

> Express $-i$ in form $re^{i\theta}$

$r=1$ is simple enough.

As on an Argand diagram $-i$ will be at $(0,-1)$ is $\theta = 3\pi/2$ here? or $-\pi/2$ to get it $-\pi < \theta < \pi$

Is the answer $e^{3i\pi/2}$ or $e^{-i\pi/2}$ or am I completely wrong somewhere?

Comment: $e^{3i\pi/2}$ and $e^{-i\pi/2}$ are the same things.

Answer (score 1):

The angle $\theta$ in the polar form is not uniquely defined. Typically, you choose to specify it from a given range, i.e. $(0, 2 \pi)$ or $(-\pi,\pi)$.

Since $r e^{i \theta} = r \left ( \cos (\theta) + i \sin (\theta) \right )$, you can see that, due to the periodicity of $\sin$ and $\cos$, $r e^{i \theta} = r e^{i (\theta + 2 \pi n)}$.

Therefore $-i = e^{3/2 i \pi} = e^{-1/2 i \pi}$ and $= e^{-5/2 i \pi}$ for example.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we know:

$$a+bi=\left|a+bi\right|e^{\arg\left(a+bi\right)i}=\left|a+bi\right|\left(\cos\left(\arg\left(a+bi\right)\right)+\sin\left(\arg\left(a+bi\right)\right)i\right)$$

---

$$-i=$$
$$\left|-i\right|e^{\arg\left(-i\right)i}=$$
$$\sqrt{\Re(-i)^2+\Im(-i)^2}e^{\arg\left(-i\right)i}=$$
$$\sqrt{0^2+(-1)^2}e^{\arg\left(-i\right)i}=$$
$$\sqrt{(-1)^2}e^{\arg\left(-i\right)i}=$$
$$|-1|e^{\arg\left(-i\right)i}=$$
$$1e^{\arg\left(-i\right)i}=$$
$$e^{\frac{3}{2}\pi i}=$$
$$e^{\left(\left(\frac{3}{2}\pi\right)-2\pi\right) i}=$$
$$e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}i}$$